# Add read permission for USB storage Oculus GO Unity C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusgo

I’m developing a Unity app for an Oculus GO Headset. It’s written in C#. 
I have a Micro USB stick for the headset and I am able to see its contents and play them in Moon Player VR from

**OculusTV > Settings.apk (Downloaded from here)(It’s essentially the Android settings menu) > Storage.**

I am also able to open it with JS USB OTG apk I sideloaded.

Now, as for the app: I got it to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
But the amount of videos I am able to store solely on the headset is only 32GB.

I’d like to display from my app, the same permissions dialogue JS USB OTG does for reading USB storage.

**And to be able to play videos from the USB from the code with my logic on top.**

A Video Player I used to play a video from the USB Stick displaying the path of the video as content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/4E43-F552%3Alake.mp4.

The way I am running Videos from storage outside the app now:

```
        VideoPlayer videoPlayer = sphere.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        videoPlayer.url = "/sdcard/Movies/lake.mp4";
        videoPlayer.Play();
```

The current permissions in the Android Manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: You are talking about two usb sticks?

Comment: The headset is connected to your phone? How?

Comment: I have one USB Stick put in the headset. This is it:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kingston-Technology-DTDUO3-64GB-micro-USB/dp/B00LIXJ0OU/ref=sr_1_13?keywords=usb%2Bmicro%2Busb%2Bstick&qid=1576232348&sr=8-13&th=1
It is not connected to my phone. 
The app I am building is only supposed to run on Oculus.

Comment: You better had posted a picture of the Oculus... So it comes with 32GB internal memory? And that memory is reachable under /sdcard ? And now you put the usb stick in and you wanna know its path? Well if it is /storage/4E43-F552 in your phone then it will be the same on the Oculus.

Comment: So it comes with 32GB internal memory? Yep
And that memory is reachable under /sdcard? Yep
And now you put the USB stick in and you wanna know its path? Yep
Well if it is /storage/4E43-F552 in your phone then it will be the same on the Oculus. Nope :(

I actually found the path of the video in the USB Stick

And besides the path, I want to actually gain the permission to read the USB from my app.

Comment: Have you tried getExternalFilesDirs() the second item? And ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?

Comment: I cannot get the getExternalFiles() to run as Application.Context.getExternalFiles is returning Application does not contain a definition for context.
I found this and I already checked that directory https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148
What do you mean by the second item?
Is ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE a permission.

Comment: getExternalFiles() does not exist. There are getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs(). I talked about the latter. Your link is incomplete so you could not check what i said.

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() is what I meant sorry.
I just cannot include the proper Android.Content in my Project

Comment: Then from where are you calling the function?

Comment: I'm trying to call it from the Awake() function of an OnStartVideo script attached to a scene. It's the same place I'm usually adding the video to my sphere.

Comment: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/4E43-F552%3Alake.mp4` . You can let the user pick that content scheme using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: You see thats the same 4E43-F552! Uid of the stick.

Comment: Would you mind putting an example piece of code?
Yes, I noticed the UID as well

Comment: Sorry, i do not program in Unity.

Comment: It's okay 
I've been struggling with that for a week...